# Visual studio 2022 shows blurry font on external monitor on windows 11

Tags: fonts, menu, visual-studio-2022

I have laptop connected to an external monitor Dell 2412. Upon upgrading to vs2022, I am noticing the visual studio menu fonts got blurred. It is usable but a nagging issue. I tried to clear the clear-type font and did some font adjustments in Tools > Options but this does not help.

It does not look that way on the laptop screen. Also other applications are just fine. Is there any way to fix other than to change my monitor?

[image]

[image]

PS: The font is fine when the project is loading... After the project loads it gets screwed up

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following fixed the issue, in VS 2022:

Go to Tools > Text Sharp > General

Set:

Text rendering mode: Auto

Text Formatting Mode: Ideal

Text hinting mode: Auto

Targets: both options checked

Comment: see the above answer from @o-super: you will need to add TextSharp extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SergeyVlasov.TextSharp

Comment: Thank you!  I was going crazy wondering why all of a sudden my text was all blurry.

Answer (score 1):

In order to apply the fix from Samuel
you will need to extention Text Sharp from this link:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SergeyVlasov.TextSharp

Comment: It would be better to comment this under Samuel's answer or to suggest an edit to Samuel's answer adding this information instead of posting it as a separate answer. This on its own is _not_ an answer to the question.

Comment: I don't use stackoverflow a lot, next time I will be more careful on where I place an answer. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I can assume that you have two screens of different sizes.
visual studio loads the screen dimensions and it config the environment based on the targeted screen (during VS startup). so  you need to close VS and reopen it in the desried screen . and VS will adapt it self to the targeted one.