# Visual Studio 2022 change scaling

Tags: visual-studio-2022

My display looks a little blurry in Visual Studio 2022, I need help finding a setting to change the scaling.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Wjxx.png)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72366725/visual-studio-2022-shows-blurry-font-on-external-monitor-on-windows-11

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual studio 2022 shows blurry font on external monitor on windows 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72366725/visual-studio-2022-shows-blurry-font-on-external-monitor-on-windows-11)