# Only HTML-containing files are blurry in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2022, blurry

I'm using 125% scaling on my secondary monitor.

When I open Visual studio 2022 all files look good, only the files which contain HTML code (in my case .aspx, .ascx, .master files) are blurry the other (.cs, .css, .config) files are sharp.
The "Optimize rendering for screens with different pixel densities" setting in VS2022 is turned on.

On my laptop monitor, which uses 100% scaling, it looks just fine.

I also have the setting in Windows under "Advanced scaling settings" called "Let Windows try to fix apps so they're not blurry" turned on.

Does anyone know why this problem only affects HTML-containing files?

And maybe more importantly how to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please see the answer here, [Visual studio 2022 shows blurry font on external monitor on windows 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72366725/visual-studio-2022-shows-blurry-font-on-external-monitor-on-windows-11)

Comment: I just reopened VS2022 from my secondary monitor and everything looks fine now. This really is wrinkling my brain. I tried this a few hours ago, but then it didn't seem to work. I tried Textsharp, that didn't do anything but make the other text aliased.

Comment: Visual Studio sometimes has weird scaling issues and I wonder if that is what is happening here.  Maybe try messing with the scaling setting for your displays in the resolution settings on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textsharp made no difference, it only made the sharp text look aliased. The blurry text still was blurry.

It seems reopening Visual Studio from my secondary screen did the trick.
I'm certain I tried this a few hours ago as well, and it didn't seem to work then.

For now, it seems fixed.